# Simplified prepaid phone balance with Tasker

Tags: sms, tasker

On my prepaid phone, I can receive current balance as text message responses. They are five messages, four indicating the balance itself and some additional bonuses, and one more indicating the remaining SMS count. However this requires sending a message to the balance number, reading each of the responses, then deleting them manually. How can I set up a simple notification as replacement for this using Tasker?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of how I have implemented it. Besides Tasker, I also used:

- [AutoNotification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autonotification), for a richer notification.
- [SMS Popup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup), for suppressing SMS notification for the balance responses.
- [SMS Auto Delete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jfk.android), for silently deleting those SMS responses after a while.

[image: Notification sample]

### Profiles

- **Request Balance on Calls -** on outgoing call: *Balance Before Call*, on exit: *Balance After Call*.
- **Process Received Balance -** on SMS received from the balance numbers: *Process Balance*.
- **Show Balance Summary -** on *Balance* variable set: *Show Balance*.

### Tasks

- **Balance Before Call**

  ```
  AutomatedBalance = Yes
  CheckConsumption = Yes
  Request balance by SMS
  ```
- **Balance After Call**

  ```
  Wait 15 seconds
  Unset CheckConsumption
  Request balance by SMS
  Flash "Balance has been requested"
  ```
- **Process Balance**

  ```
  response = number from each SMS response
  Case SMS sender is the one responsible for
      Bonus balance
          BonusBalance = response
      SMS balance
          SMSBalance = response
      Normal balance
          BalanceConsumption = (Balance - response)
          Balace = response
      Favorite-number balance
          FavoriteBalanceConsumption = (FavoriteBalance - response)
          FavoriteBalance = response
      Same-carrier balance
          CarrierBalanceConsumption = (CarrierBalance - response)
          CarrierBalance = response
      Local landline balance, then
          LocalBalanceConsumption = (LocalBalance - response)
          LocalBalance = response
      Unknown sender
          # This normally means an error, when none of the above have been fired
          Append "(previous)" to Balance
  ```
- **Show Balance**

  ```
  If CheckConsumption
      If Balance is not currency
          notify "Error while getting the balance in the beginning of call"
      Exit from task
  Wait 5 seconds
  If Balance is currency
      If FavoriteBalanceConsumption > 0
          consumption = FavoriteBalanceConsumption
          Prefix consumption with "Call to favorite (min) consumed"
      Else if CarrierBalanceConsumption > 0
          consumption = CarrierBalanceConsumption + LocalBalanceConsumption +
              BalanceConsumption
          Prefix consumption with "Call to same-carrier number consumed"
      Else if LocalBalanceConsumption > 0
          consumption = LocalBalanceConsumption + BalanceConsumption
          Prefix consumption with "Call to local number consumed"
      Else if BalanceConsumption > 0
          consumption = BalanceConsumption
          Prefix consumption with "Regular call consumed"
      Else if AutomatedBalance
          consumption = "Free call"
      Else
          consumption = "Phone balance"
      Notify consumption and all balances
      Set all unset balances to zero
      Set all consumptions to zero
  Else
      previous_balance = number from balance prefixed with "Previous balance is"
      notify "Error while getting the balance", previous_balance
  Unset AutomatedBalance
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Action -> Event -> Phone -> Received Text

- Type: SMS
- Sender: Phone balance
- Content: *balance*

New Task -> Variables -> Variable Set

- Name: %SMSBALANCE
- To: %SMSRB

Add Task -> Alert -> Popup

- Title: balance text: [see in variables] ...

VOILA